# Filtering a table via another table's values

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables:

Value

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Peter |
|  2 | Jane  |
|  3 | Joe   |
+----+-------+
```

Filter

```
+----+---------+------+
| id | valueid | type |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 |       1 | A    |
|  2 |       1 | B    |
|  3 |       1 | C    |
|  4 |       1 | D    |
|  5 |       2 | A    |
|  6 |       2 | C    |
|  7 |       2 | E    |
|  8 |       3 | A    |
|  9 |       3 | D    |
+----+---------+------+
```

I need to retrieve the values from the Value table where the related Filter table does not contain the type 'B' or 'C'
So in this quick example this would be only Joe.

Please note this is a DB2 DB and i have limited permissions to run selects only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or also a `NOT IN (<*fullselect*)`  predicate:
Only that my result is 'Joe', not 'Jane' - and the data constellation would point to that ...

```
WITH
-- your input, sans reserved words
val(id,nam) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Peter' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Jane'  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'Joe'   FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
)
,
filtr(id,valueid,typ) AS (
          SELECT 1,1,'A' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 2,1,'B' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 3,1,'C' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 4,1,'D' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 5,2,'A' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 6,2,'C' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 7,2,'E' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 8,3,'A' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
UNION ALL SELECT 9,3,'D' FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
)
-- real query starts here
SELECT
  *
FROM val
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT valueid FROM filtr WHERE typ IN ('B','C')
)
;
-- out  id |  nam  
-- out ----+-------
-- out   3 | Joe
```

Or also, a failing left join:

```
SELECT
  val.*
FROM val
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT valueid FROM filtr WHERE typ IN ('B','C')
) filtr
ON filtr.valueid = val.id
WHERE valueid IS NULL
```

Comment: The OP says "Jane", you say "Peter", and I say "Joe". LOL

Comment: I had erroneously joined over `USING(id)` instead of `val.id` <-> `filtr.valueid` .. It's 'Joe' after all - fixed mine in the meantime ...

Comment: Good +1. A word of caution: I usually avoid `NOT IN` since it doesn't work in the presence of nulls.

Comment: Yes that was my bad, i'm actually looking for Joe here.

Comment: ... and a third way, just added to my response, using a failing left join. I don't know about DB2 as well as I used to, but , depending on the DBMS, one of the 3 ways of doing it is better than the other two. Worth exploring ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXISTS`, as in:

```
select *
from value v
where not exists (
  select null from filter f
  where f.valueid = v.id and f.type in ('B', 'C')
);
```

Result:

```
 ID  NAME 
 --- -----
 3   Joe
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d65d5b7d3d2091ed041f5890583f3ac0).